# Can the spin connection be defined entirely from a structure group reduction?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

I understand from [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01410.pdf) that reducing the structure group $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ of the frame field $FX$ of a world manifold $X^4$ to the $SO(4,\mathbb{R})$ group entails the Levi-Civita connection as the (unique torsion-free) connection that preserves the reduction.

Can we define the spin connection as a structure group reduction? For instance does a structure reduction from $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ or $SL(4,\mathbb{R})$ to either $Spin(4)$ or $Spin^c(4)$ produces the spin connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reductions of structure group are not sufficient. The groups $Spin(4)$ and $Spin^c(4)$ are not realized as subgroups of $GL^+(4,\mathbb R)$. The natural homomorphism $Spin(4)\to GL^+(4,\mathbb R)$ (coming from the action of $Spin(4)$ on $\mathbb R^4$) has image $SO(4)$ and two element kernel. To get to the spin connection you first have to reduce the structure group to $SO(4)$. In a second step, you have to extend the structure group to $Spin(4)$. Basically, this means that you have to define a principal $Spin(4)$-bundle such that the reduction by the two element kernel of the canonical homomorphism $Spin(4)\to SO(4)$ reproduces the $SO(4)$-reduction of the frame bundle you started from.

Such an extension exists only if the second Stiefel-Whitney class of your manifold $M$ (a characteristic class in $H^2(M,\mathbb Z_2)$) is zero. If this is the case, then the extension is not unique in general, this is related to the first Stiefel-Whitney class in $H^1(M,\mathbb Z_2)$. Therefore the whole process is referred to as "a choice of spin-structure". For $Spin^c(4)$ the story is similar, apart from the fact that $Spin^c(4)$-structures always exist. (This is not true in higher dimensions.)

Comment: Is your answer specific to GL$^+$(4,R)? What if we take GL(4,R)? Since Spin(4) is realized in GL(4,R), an the spin connection arise from the reduction of GL(4,R) with Spin(4)? Or is the second lifting step also required?

Comment: No, the map from $Spin(4)$ to $GL(4,\mathbb R)$ has values in $GL^+(4,\mathbb R)$ (since $Spin(4)$ is connected). The point is that $Spin(4)$ is not a subgroup of $GL(4,\mathbb R)$ but a two-fold covering of the group $SO(4)$.

Comment: However, there is a isomorphism between $Spin(4)$ and $SU(2) \times SU(2)$, and $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ is a subgroup of $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$. Is an isomorphism not sufficient in this case?

Comment: I don't see how $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ would be a subgroup of $GL(4,\mathbb R)$. For this action on $\mathbb R^4$ that is used in finding the isomorphism to $Spin(4)$, the pairs $(\mathbb I,\mathbb I)$ and $(-\mathbb I,-\mathbb I)$ act in the same way on $\mathbb R^4$, which exactly leads to the two-fold covering phenomenon we were talking about.

Comment: Hello, would you be so kind as to have a look at my latest question (building upon this answer)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656283/an-attempt-to-derive-the-spin-connection-from-a-structure-reduction

Comment: If using Spin(3,1), is the story the same? I am told $\exp CL(3,1)$ maps to $GL^+(4)$ and Spin(3,1) is in $\exp CL(3,1)$. So is Spin(3,1) a special case where this works?

Comment: The key difference between $Spin(p,q)$ and $SO(p,q)$ is the the latter maps injectively to $GL(p+q,R)$, while the former the corresponding homomorphism is never injective. So whatever you do, it will not become a subgroup.

Comment: Previously I asked this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657402/does-the-exponential-of-a-bivector-pseudo-scalar-in-cl3-1-maps-to-rm-spin and was told that $\exp (<\text{bivector}> + <\text{pseudo-scalar}> ) \cong {\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$. It is also the case that $CL(3,1) \cong M(4)$, and that $\exp M(4) \to GL^+(4)$. It appears that if I take a special representation of  $GL^+(4)$ and $ {\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ using exponentials of multivectors, then the quotient $GL^+(4)/ {\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ can be taken?

Comment: The problem is that in dimension 4 the half spin representation happen to be 4 dimensional. What you write in the last comment refers to (one of the half-)spin representations of $Spin(3,1)$. This is not what would be needed in the discussion of reductions of structure group. To talk about reductions of structure group, you need the standard representation of $GL(4)$ to correspond to the tangent bundle of the underlying manifold. In the picture you are trying to develop, it would correspond to one of the spin bundles, so there is no real relation.

Comment: Lets completely forget about ${\rm Spin}(3,1)$ and only worry about ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ . Because ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$, unlike ${\rm Spin}(3,1)$, fits inside $\exp CL(3,1)$, and $\exp CL(3,1) \cong {\rm GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$. Since $\exp CL(3,1) \cong {\rm GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$, wouldn't $\exp CL(3,1)$ correspond to an action on the tangent bundle of the underlying manifold? Then I can define a connection from the reduction ${\rm GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})/{\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$? The connection would then not be quite the spin connection, but the spin^c connection?

Comment: There is no difference between Spin and $Spin^c$ in this respect. The point about Spin and $Spin^c$ structures is that you get bundles (namely the spin bundles) which are not available without this structure. If you could get these structures from reductions of structure group, this would not be the case, you could only get finer decompositions of bundles that were previously available. You have to distinguish between the spin representations and the standard representation here even though they have the same real dimension.

Comment: First, thank you for providing me with so many answers. However, I am still not clear if you see the coincidence I am talking about. First, I agree with you 100% that what you say is true in the general case. However, I am stating there is a coincidence that holds only in $Spin^c(3,1)$ (e.g. it fails in $Spin^c(4)$ and $Spin(3,1)$), such that $Spin^c(3,1) \in \exp CL(3,1)$, and $\exp CL(3,1)$ generates $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ up to isomorphism. *In this case alone*, the quotient $\exp CL(3,1)/Spin^c(3,1)$ , gives spin connection without having to do a structure lift, no?

Comment: $
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\Gl{\mathrm{Gl}}
$Following the standard [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras) of real Clifford algebras into matrix algebras or direct sums of matrix algebras $\phi : \Cl(3,1) \cong M(4, \R)$ as algebras, where $M(4,\R)$ is the algebra of real $4{\times}4$ matrices. Thus
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
  \Cl(3,1) @>{\phi}>> M(4,\R) \\
  @V{\exp}VV @VV{\exp}V \\
  \exp\Cl(3,1) @>>{\phi}> \Gl^+(4, \R)
\end{CD}$$
commutes as a diagrams of group homomorphisms.

Comment: Finally, since $Spin^c(3,1) \in \exp CL(3,1)$, then $\phi$ embeds $Spin^c(3,1)$ into $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$, allowing us to take the quotient $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})/Spin^c(3,1)$ without having to introduce a spin bundle. This entails a connection that preserves $Spin^c(3,1)$ as the result of a structure reduction from $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ to $Spin^c(3,1)$.

Comment: Maybe if I call it a Spin-preserving connection it would be more palatable than calling is a spin connection?

Comment: I am afraid, this is still a misunderstanding: The quotient $GL^+(4,\mathbb R)/SO(3,1)$ is isomorphic to the space of Lorentzian inner products on $\mathbb R^4$. Taking the associated bundle to the frame bundle of $TM$, one obtains a bundle whose sections are Lorentzian metrics on $M$ (there is no direct relation to connections). It is then a theorem, that such a metric determines a unique torsion-free connection on $TM$, which can be interpreted on the the frame bundle (and on the spin frame bundle). The construction you suggest would lead to a metric on the spin bundle, not a connection.