# Representing the spin group with rotors

Tags: group-theory, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

In these notes [1](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/LieGroups-2012/cliffalgsandspingroups.pdf), the author claims on page 7 that

> One can define the Lie algebra of Spin(n) in terms of quadratic
> elements of the Clifford algebra. This is what we will do here.

The author then proceeds with creating an exponential of bivector.

My understanding is that exponentials of bivector are rotors. And that rotors are in SO(n), not spin(n).

How is the author able to claim a rotor is representation of spins? I cannot see where (or if) he modifies the rotor in any way to get the spin.

The other element I do not understand is that I was told by a user on this site [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4640461/188569) that ${\rm Spin}(n)$ is not in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. However, rotors are. Thus, if one represents ${\rm Spin}(n)$ with rotor, wouldn't that imply ${\rm Spin}(n)$ is in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ (thus contradiction).

Comment: A rotor, by definition, is an element of $Spin(n)$. If that's not clear, what definition of rotor are you using?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I am using this $R=\exp \frac{1}{2} B$, where $B$ is a bivector.

Comment: ...so why do you think $R \in GL(n)$? $\exp B$ is an element of the Clifford algebra, it's not even a function or a matrix. It seems like maybe you're making a type error. A Clifford algebra element $X$ is in $Spin(n)$ if $X^{-1}vX$ is a vector for all vectors $v$ and if $\widetilde XX = 1$ (or $\pm1$, definitions vary) where $\widetilde X$ is reversal. The exponential of a bivector fits this definition easily. The element $X$ then induces a map $$v \mapsto X^{-1}vX$$ which is in SO(n), and this representation is surjective with kernel $\pm1$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff  The bivector of clifford algegra 2D can be represented as the pauli matrix $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. For instance,  $B=b \sigma_1   \sigma_2$. Therefor $\exp (B)$ is representable as an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: **Represented**. This is what I mean by type error. Consider the following: is it true that $3 \in 5$? This is a "valid" question if you base mathematics in set theory, but hopefully its clear that even so the question is nonsensical. In a sense it doesn't have an answer: if we use von Neumann ordinals the $3 \in 5$, but if we use Zermelo ordinals then $3 \not\in 5$...

Comment: ... This is exactly the mistake you are making: we can represent a bivector as a $2\times2$ complex matrix $B$, but then what is $Bv$ when $v$ is a 2D complex column vector? The answer has nothing to do with the *bivector*, and is an artifact of the *representation*. We could just as well use other non-equivalent matrix representations of the Clifford algebra.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff A complex vector in the clifford algebra is $v = z_1 \sigma_1 + z_2 \sigma_2$. If you multiply the matrix representation of v with the matrix representation of $\exp B$, you get the correct end result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142957/discussion-between-nicholas-todoroff-and-anon21).

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that "exponentials" are not well-defined in themselves. If you have a Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, you have an exponential map $\mathfrak{g}\to G$, but it depends on $G$, not just on $\mathfrak{g}$. And there are usually several groups $G$ with the same $\mathfrak{g}$ (they are of course not unrelated).

So here $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is the Lie algebra of $SO(n)$ and of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ (because they are isogenous), which means there are exponential maps $\mathfrak{so}(n)\to SO(n)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(n)\to \operatorname{Spin}(n)$, which are related but different (namely, the first one is obtained from the second using the natural surjection $\operatorname{Spin}(n)\to SO(n)$).

And indeed, $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ is not a subgroup of $GL(n)$, but this is not a contradiction.

Comment: So $\exp \mathfrak{so}$ maps to some elements of $Spin(n)$ (but not all)? Otherwise, since $\mathfrak{so}$ is in $\mathfrak{gl}$, then I would think $\exp \mathfrak{so}$ would be in $\exp \mathfrak{gl}$ (making Spin in GL)

Comment: Anon21 is talking about the exponential of a bivector in their question, which is perfectly well defined. A bivector in this case is an element of a Clifford algebra, and we define the exponential through its power series.