# Does the exponential of a bivector + pseudo-scalar in Cl(3,1) maps to ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$?

Tags: group-theory

In [1](https://electrichandleslide.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/seiberg-witten-theory-1-spin-spinc-structures/) and in [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure#SpinC_structures), ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ is defined as:

$$
{\rm Spin}^c(3,1) ={\rm U}(1) \times ({\rm Spin}(3,1) /\{\pm 1\})
$$

---

1. I would like to know if the exponential between a bivector + a pseudo-scalar of Cl(3,1) maps to ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$.

---

I start with a multivector $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{b}$ of Cl(3,1), where $\mathbf{f}$ is a bivector and $\mathbf{b}$ is a pseudo-scalar.

I note that its exponential is $\exp ( \mathbf{f} +\mathbf{b})$. The part $R=\exp \mathbf{f}$ maps to the ${\rm Spin}(3,1)$ group, and the part $\exp \mathbf{b}$ maps to ${\rm U}(1)$.

So far we have ${\rm Spin}(3,1) \times {\rm U}(1)$.

We are almost there but the part $\{\pm 1\}$ causes me confusion.

What does $\{\pm 1\}$ mean here? Does $\{\pm 1\}$ refers to the double covers of ${\rm Spin}(3,1)$ over ${\rm SO}(3,1)$?

If so, can I make the following argument: The double cover of $R=\exp\mathbf{f}$ is realized with $v' = Rv R^{-1}$ (first cover) and with $v' = -Rv(-R)^{-1}$ (second cover). However, here the exponentiation only gives me $R=\exp \mathbf{f}$ and not $-R$, then I realize a single cover only. Consequently, it is the case that

$$
\exp (\mathbf{f} +\mathbf{b}) \to {\rm Spin}^c(3,1)
$$

?

Comment: Your brackets are wrong in your first equation. Your first source says $$\mathrm{Spin}^c(3,1) = U(1)\times(\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)/\{\pm1\})$$ which is correct (though really silly as a definition). Also, writing this as a "quotient" by $\mathbb Z_2$ is not good practice since a priori these sets are unrelated.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thank you; I've edited the question.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Also, can you explain why its silly?

Comment: Its just bad to use as a *definition*. $\mathrm{Spin}^c(3,1)$ is the spin group of the complexification of $\mathrm{Cl}(3,1)$. Defining it as above, on the other hand, is completely unenlightening and seemingly random.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff  This definition is illuminating for physics, however. Spacetime is CL(3,1), so if $Spin^c$ associates to the exponential of bivectors+pseudoscalars, thats quite illuminating.

Comment: Which is exactly why you shouldn't define it to have that relationship at the outset. If it is a **definition** then you are **defining** it to be true, it doesn't illuminate anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand\Spin{\mathrm{Spin}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}
\newcommand\grade[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
$Here $\{\pm1\}$ is what it looks like: it is the multiplicative subgroup of $\Cl(3,1)$ composed of identity element and its additive inverse. Because $\Spin(3,1) \subseteq \Cl(3,1)$ it makes sense to quotient by this.

We should make clear our definition of $\Spin$. There are two common definitions in the real case. We canonically identify $\R$ and $\R^4$ as a subsets of $\Cl(3,1)$. Let $\Cl(3,1)^\times$ be the multiplicative group of invertible elements of $\Cl(3,1)$, let $\Cl^{(0)}(3,1)$ denote the even subalgebra of $\Cl(3,1)$, let $\hat X$ be the unique automorphism on $\Cl(3,1)$ such that $\hat x = -x$ when $x \in \R^4$, and let $\widetilde X$ be the unique antiautomorphism which is the identity on $\R^4$. Then we define
$$
  \Spin_+(3,1) = \{X \in \Cl^{(0)}(3,1)^\times \;:\; \hat X^{-1}\R^4X \subseteq \R^4,\: \widetilde XX = 1\},
$$$$
  \Spin_\pm(3,1) = \{X \in \Cl^{(0)}(3,1)^\times \;:\; \hat X^{-1}\R^4X \subseteq \R^4,\: \widetilde XX = \pm1\}.
$$
Both of these groups get called "the $\Spin$ group of $\Cl(3,1)$", but they are not isomorphic. Only $\Spin_\pm(3,1)$ covers $\mathrm{SO}(3,1)$, and the fundamental reason we need $\pm1$ and not just $1$ is because $-1$ is not a square in $\R$. Evidently if we only want to consider bivector exponentials then $\Spin_+(3,1)$ is what we want, and this group only covers the identity-connected component of $\mathrm{SO}(3,1)$. But this group is not the group of bivector exponentials like you suggest; it is the group of $\pm$ bivector exponentials:
$$
  \Spin_+(3,1) = \pm\exp\Cl^2(3,1) = \{\pm e^B \;:\; B \in \Cl^2(3,1)\}
$$
where $\Cl^2(3,1)$ is the space of bivectors. There are bivectors $B$ such that $-e^B \ne e^{B'}$ for all $B'$.

When we complexify $\Cl(3,1)$ to $\Cl_c(3,1)$ we also get a Clifford algebra and we define the corresponding $\Spin$ group
$$
  \Spin^c(3,1) = \{X \in \Cl_c^{(0)}(3,1)^\times \;:\; \hat X^{-1}\C^4X \subseteq \C^4,\: \widetilde XX = 1\}.
$$
It's worth noting that the signature $(3,1)$ is irrelevant because all quadratic forms over $\C^4$ are equivalent up to degeneracy. Here we need $1$ rather than $\pm1$ because $i^2 = -1$; if we had used $\pm1$ instead then we would get a *quadruple cover* of $\mathrm{SO}(\C; 4)$.

Now lets unpack what's happening with
$$
  \Spin^c(3,1) \cong U(1)\times(\Spin_+(3,1)/\{\pm1\}).
$$
Let's define $U(1)$ explicitly as $U(1) = \{z \in \C^\times \;:\; \bar zz = 1\}$. If we complexify $\Spin(3,1)$ directly to $\C\otimes_\R\Spin_\pm(3,1)$ then we end up with unormalized elements because $\C$ is unrestricted. So rather than $\C$ we need to consider just $U(1)$, and since we're only interested in the group structure a direct product suffices. So you might think we want
$$
  U(1)\times\Spin_+(3,1)
$$
but there's an issue: $(-z, s) \ne (z, -s)$ for $z \in U(1)$ and $s \in \Spin_+(3,1)$. What we need to do is erase the distinction between $\pm s$; this is exactly what the quotient $\Spin_+(3,1)/\{\pm1\}$ does. Hence
$$
  \Spin^c(3,1) \cong U(1)\times(\Spin_+(3,1)/\{\pm1\}).
$$
Note that the same reasoning also tells us
$$
  \Spin^c(3,1) \cong (U(1)/\{\pm1\})\times\Spin_+(3,1).
$$

Finally, let's consider the exponentials of $\Cl^2(3,1) \oplus \Cl^4(3,1)$, i.e. of bivectors and pseudoscalars togethers. Pseudoscalars always commute with the even subalgebra of a Clifford algebra; hence for any $B \in \Cl^2(3,1)$ and $I \in \Cl^4(3,1)$
$$
  e^{B+I} = e^Be^I = e^Ie^B.
$$
Since $I^2 \leq 0$ these quantities act just like imaginary numbers; in particular
$$
  \exp\Cl^4(3,1) \cong U(1).
$$
We can discover that $\Spin_+(3,1)\cap\exp\Cl^4(3,1) = \{\pm1\}$, with a proof provided below the divide. It follows from this that
$$\begin{aligned}
  \{e^{B+I} \;:\; B \in \Cl^2(3,1),\: I \in \Cl^4(3,1)\}
  &= [\Spin_+(3,1)][\exp\Cl^4(3,1)]
\\
  &\cong U(1)\times(\Spin_+(3,1)/\{\pm1\})
\\
  &\cong \Spin^c(3,1).
\end{aligned}$$

---

Suppose $B \ne 0$ is a bivector. We see that $B^2 \in \R\oplus\Cl^4(3,1)$ and that even powers of $B$ remain in this space. Now
$$
  e^B = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{i!}B^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{(2i)!}B^{2i} + B\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{(2i+1)!}B^{2i}.
$$
The first term is in $\R\oplus\Cl^4(3,1)$. The second term can be put in the form $B(b + I)$ where $b \in \R$ and $I \in \Cl^4(3,1)$. Then we see
$$
  B(b + I) = bB + BI
$$
with both of these terms grade 2. If this quantity is nonzero then $e^B \not\in \exp\Cl^4(3,1)$ since this latter set contains only grade 0 and grade 4 components. If it is zero then $bB = -BI$. If $b$ is nonzero then $B = -BI/b$, but also $B = bBI$. Since $B \ne 0$ then also $BI \ne 0$, so $b = -1/b$ which is impossible over $\R$. If $b = 0$ then $I = 0$ and
$$
  0 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{(2i+1)!}B^{2i}
    = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{2i+1}{(2i)!}B^{2i}
$$
From which it follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
  \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{(2i)!}B^{2i}
  &= -\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1{(2i-1)!}B^{2i}
  = -B^2\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1{(2i-1)!}B^{2i-2}
\\
  &= -B^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{(2i+1)!}B^{2i}
  = 0
\end{aligned}$$
which means $e^B = 0$ which is impossible. Thus it must have been that $B(b + I) \ne 0$ and so the only time $\Spin_+(3,1)$ intersects $\exp\Cl^4(3,1)$ is when $B = 0$:
$$
  \Spin_+(3,1)\cap\exp\Cl^4(3,1) = \{\pm e^0\} = \{\pm1\}.
$$