# Does $\exp \mathbf{u}$ where $\mathbf{u} \in \text{CL}(3,1)$ maps to $\text{GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ or its double cover?

Tags: group-theory

I am interested in the 3+1D case, where low dimensional coincidences play a role. I am also interested in the Spin group which can be represented as the exponential of bivectors.

---

In 2D, the picture is clear to me.

A multivector of $\text{CL}(2)$ can be represented with the following matrix

$$
a+ x \mathbf{e}_1 + y \mathbf{e}_2 + b \mathbf{e}_1\mathbf{e}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
a+x & -b+y\\
b+y & a-x
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since this is a representation of the $2\times 2$ matrices, it follows that

$$
\exp \mathbf{u} \to \text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})
$$

Here the $\text{Spin}(2)$ is included because $\text{Spin}(2)=\text{SO}(2)$. $\text{Spin}(2)$ is represented with $\exp b \mathbf{e}_1\mathbf{e}_2$.

---

In the 3+1D, we can use the Dirac matrices to represent the multivectors using $4\times 4$ matrices. Both the $4\times 4$ matrices and the multivectors of 3+1D have $16$ parameters.

Let us attempt the map:

$$
\exp \mathbf{u} , \text{ where } \mathbf{u} \in \text{CL}(3,1)
$$

First we might wonder: is it in $\text{GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$?

Unlike the 2D case, here the $4\times 4$ Dirac matrices are complex valued. I took that as sign that the group is not the same as $\text{GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$. Here the $\text{Spin}(3,1)$ group is included in $\exp \mathbf{u}$, but for any n, it is not true that $\text{Spin}(n)$ is in $\text{GL}^+(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Does $\exp \mathbf{u}$, where $\mathbf{u} \in \text{CL}(3,1)$ map to either $\text{GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ or its double cover? If it maps to $\text{GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$, does it imply that $\text{Spin}(3,1)$ is in $\text{GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ - is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\Gl{\mathrm{Gl}}
$Following the standard [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras) of real Clifford algebras into matrix algebras or direct sums of matrix algebras $\phi : \Cl(3,1) \cong M(4, \R)$ as algebras, where $M(4,\R)$ is the algebra of real $4{\times}4$ matrices. Thus
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
  \Cl(3,1) @>{\phi}>> M(4,\R) \\
  @V{\exp}VV @VV{\exp}V \\
  \exp\Cl(3,1) @>>{\phi}> \Gl^+(4, \R)
\end{CD}$$
commutes as a diagrams of group homomorphisms.

The same sort of reasoning recovers your $\Cl(2) \to \Gl^+(2, \R)$.

Comment: I see. Since Spin(3,1) is in exp CL(3,1), can I conclude that Spin(3,1) is in $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: @Anon21 Yes, exactly the same map $\phi\circ{\exp} = {\exp}\circ\phi$ embeds $\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)$ in $\mathrm{Gl}^+(4,\mathbb R)$ since $\mathrm{Spin}(3,1) \subseteq \mathrm{Cl}(3,1)$. But note that this does not make $\mathrm{Cl}(3,1)$ or $\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)$ into subgroups of $\mathrm{Gl}(4,\mathbb R)$ because $\exp$ is not injective.

Comment: Can you have a quick look at this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4640461/188569. The poster told me the Spin connection cannot be derived from $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})/{\rm Spin}(4)$ because ${\rm Spin}(4)$ is not in $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$. Is he correct? ${\rm Spin}(3,1)$ is in $GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ but ${\rm Spin}(4)$ isn't?

Comment: I think my edit to my comment answers your question. $\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)$ is non-faithfully representable in $\mathrm{Gl}^+(4,\mathbb R)$ via the exponential, but that means this exponential map does not make it into a subgroup. Hence that quotient does not make much sense. Same for $\mathrm{Spin}(4)$.

Comment: Does the quotient $\exp {\rm CL}(3,1)/ \exp <>$ make sense, and leads to a connection?

Comment: @Anon21 $\exp(\theta B) = \exp((\theta + 2\pi)B)$ for scalar $\theta$ and simple space-like bivector $B$ with $B^2 = -1$ so the exponential is still not injective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144824/discussion-between-nicholas-todoroff-and-anon21).

Comment: My comments about non-injectivity were wrong: we are only mapping $\mathrm{Cl}(3,1) \to \mathrm{GL}^+(4,\mathbb R)$ via $\phi$ without $\exp$ involved. $\exp$ only comes in because $\mathrm{Spin}(3,1) \subseteq \exp\mathrm{Cl}(3,1)$, so in fact this shows that $\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)$ and $\exp\mathrm{Cl}(3,1)$ become subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}^+(4,\mathbb R)$ under $\phi$.

Comment: Can one make the argument that the inclusion of ${\rm Spin}(3,1)$ and ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ in ${\rm GL}^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ is a coincidence of (3,1)? i.e. it would fail for ${\rm Spin}(4)$ and ${\rm Spin}^c(4)$? Or does that not matter?

Comment: The reason for the question I asked in the previous comment is that according to your classification link, CL(4) maps (with $\phi$) to $M_2(H)$. But $\exp M_2(H)$ does not map to $GL^+(4)$ the same way $\exp M_4(R)$ does (or does it)?

Comment: @Anon21 The issue is exactly that $\mathrm{Cl}(4)$ is isomorphic to $M(2,\mathbb H)$. Since $$\mathbb H \to M(2,\mathbb C) \to M(4,\mathbb R)$$ it seems to me we would need to embed $\mathrm{Cl}(4)$ into $M(8,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: So yes I think this is coincidence stemming from the fact $3-1 = 2$ mod $8$ and $(2^{(3+1)/2})^2 = (3+1)^2$.